# Laravel doesnt send token

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, satellizer

I uploaded my app in the server i changed the folder structures i made the changes in index.php.Everything is working fine i can get the views(im using angular for the frontend and satellizer for the tokens)but whenever i try to make a call to my api through my app it doesnt send the token(im using jwt tokens).The token get on local storage but its not being send with every request,if i put the token in my url everything is working fine so im guessing its a problem with satellizer.should i change something in satellizer.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm i found it i should had change the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```